# The type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' has no property named 'textBox1'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, properties, windows-forms-designer

As people have noted in the comments, **you should never do this for a real application, as it it is bad practice**. I just want to understand how properties actually work with Visual Studio, and would never do this in a real app.

I'm getting this error whenever I try to view the design of a form I created. I went into the code and set the textBox1 field to public and added getters and setters:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85, 82);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }

        #endregion
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1 { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it compiles and runs with no errors, and there is clearly a textBox1 Property declared. Why does Visual Studio break when I use properties instead of normal fields?

EDIT: Thanks for fixing the code block, I was about to do that myself

Comment: Instead of replacing field with a public auto-property, why not just add a property that provides access to that designer generated field?

Comment: You really shouldn't try to change the designer.cs file.. use the other half of the partial class

Comment: @GrawCube, I though that using an auto property would be less verbose than having a separate property for each component. Theoretically, this should work. I'm just wondering why it doesn't.

Comment: @Sayse I know that, but this is more of an experiment than anything. I would never do that if I was writing an actual application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you are doing changes in the designer generated code manually.
If you click on the textbox in your designer you can make it public via the designer itself, and then you will not have this problem.

Comment: Can I also turn it into a property? I'm trying to make it accessible from outside the class instead, but still keeping control of setting the field (and without using Java-style getters/accessor's).

Comment: You can, because C# uses partial classes. But then don't do it in the designer generated file. right click on the form in the designer and then choose view code. There you can make a property of the edit box.